# Teste em RSpec falhando por causa de DatabaseCleaner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Eu estava tendo problema com testes faz uns 4 dias. No começo, tive problema com *"database is locked"* e no arquivo onde o `DatabaseCleaner` é configurado; mudei duas linhas que usavam `:transaction` para `:truncation` e resolvi o problema. Porém, surgiu outro:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique:
>           SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed:

O que pode ser?

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o banco de dados de testes não está sendo limpo, causando esse problema que basicamente diz que o registro não é único.

Em uma aplicação que estava desenvolvendo, esta configuração resolveu este problema (já passei por este mesmo problema).

```
config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Me dá um feedback sobre a minha resposta.

Comment: Vou testar esse código hoje e te dou um feedback. Obrigado!